# How can I display all active shopping cart price rules via a custom controller?

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, shopping-cart-price-rules

I've been asked to make a controller that will display all active shopping cart price rules. Then add description, number of uses etc.

I've created a custom module with a controller index:

```
app/code/local/Company/ActivePromotions/controllers/IndexController
```

Which contains this code:

```
class Company_ActivePromotions_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

        {
        $this->loadLayout();

        $this->renderLayout();

        }       
    }
```

The module block is here:

```
app/code/local/Company/ActivePromotions/Block/Page.php
```

It contains this code:

```
<?php

class Company_ActivePromotions_Block_Page extends Mage_Core_Block_Template

{
protected function _construct()
{
parent::_construct();
$this->setTemplate('activepromotions/1column.phtml');
}
```

The routers have been setup in `/app/code/local/Company/ActivePromotions/etc/config.xml` to display the data at: `website.com/activepromotions`

I've been advised to use this method:

```
Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Resource_Rule::updateRuleProductData
```

This is where I'm unable to get it to return anything.

How do I call the `updateRuleProductData()` method in the template file below?

```
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/activepromotions/1column.phtml
```

Should I add the `updateRuleProductData()` to the `Block.php` file or use a `Helper` in my custom module?

Comment: what version of magento are you using ? do mention the version . it will be easier to get help.

Comment: Hi, I'm using v1.9